# Error de lectura XML: contenido incorrecto tras un elemento XML del document,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Estoy cargando ajax al hacer prueba en el navegador me lanza el siguiente error:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({

        url: "otrapagina.html",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
           $('.lateral').append($(response));
        }
    });
});
```

codigo en otrapagina.html

```
<a href="#" >
    <img src="img/mail.png" alt="Correo-e"/>
    <span>Correo-e</span>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="img/snapchat.png" alt="Snapchat"/>
    <span>Snapchat</span>
</a>
<a href="#" >
    <img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter"/>
    <span>Twitter</span>
</a>
```

Código en index.html

```
<aside class="lateral">
            <img src="img/imagen.jpg">     
 </aside>
```

- El mensaje de error me aparece en Mozilla: Error de lectura XML
- En Chrome: XMLHttpRequest cannot load, origin request are only supported for protocol scheme:http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https
- En Edge corre correctamente el script
- file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/pAjax/index.html
- Uso jquery-3.2.1.js por cdn

Comment: Te sugiero agregues más detalle a tu pregunta, mencionas un error, el cual no esta especificado en el cuerpo de tu pregunta.

Comment: No encuentro ningún problema, ¿No tendrás problemas más bien con una extensión de tu explorador?

Comment: El mensaje de error me aparece en Mozilla, pero en Edge corre correctamente.

Comment: Falta indicar la versión de jQuery que estás usando. Es conveniente que crees un [mcve].

Comment: ¿Como es que estas abriendo el archivo donde se encutra este código? ¿Abres un archivo `.html` directamente (`ejemplo: file://...`) o lo ejecutas via servido (`ejemplo: http://localhost/...`)?

Comment: *  En el momento esta asi : file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/pAjax/index.html ,
*  Version de jquery: jquery-3.2.1.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es debido a que estás intentado acceder a un archivo local a través de `file:/` o `C:`, dependiendo como lo interpreta el explorador.

Te recomiendo que realices tus pruebas con un [`Servidor Web`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servidor_web), si estás acostumbrado a las aplicaciones de Google Chrome puedes usar [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb), el cual te habilita un puerto para accedes de tus diferentes exploradores.

---

Solo seleccionas la carpeta que contiene tus archivos HTML e ingresas al link que te indica.

[image: Web Server for Chrome]

*Recuerda que puede ser `127.0.0.1` o `localhost`, por si tienes problemas con algún explorador.*

Comment: Genial!, todo funciona ok