# Porque no se muestran mis font face?

Tags: html5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
archivo font face

```
@font-face {
    font-family:Hurme1;
    font-weight: 48;
    src:url(fonts/HurmeGeometricSans3Bold.otf);

}
---------------------------------------------------------------
index.html
  <link href="./css/fonts.css"rel="stylesheet" >
-----------------------------------------------------------
styles.csss
h1{
font-family:Hurme1;
    color :#FFFFFF;
    text-align: center

}
```

Comment: Seguramente el navegador no tiene acceso a tu archivo de fuentes. Agrega un árbol de directorios de tu proyecto, para ver las rutas que estás usando y que deberías usar.

Comment: Sería bueno que tus pruebas lo realices en un Servidor Web, favor revisa la respuesta que hice https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92376#92400.

Answer (score 1):

Es porque la url no esta apuntando bien a tu carpeta fonts; si te encuentras en la carpeta css primero debes de salir de esa carpeta y luego entrar a la de fuentes para mandar a llamarlas desde tu archivo css y trata siempre de agregarle comillas a la URL para que sean mas legibles. En tu archivo index solo debes de mandar a llamar tu style.css

CSS.

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Hurme1';
    font-weight: 48;
    src:url('../fonts/HurmeGeometricSans3Bold.otf');
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Hurme1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En la url donde se marca el error se indica que la carpeta `fuentes` esta dentro de la carpeta css:

```
../tespage/css/fuentes/..
```

Pero segun la estructura que tienes, ademas de que no hay una carpeta llamada `fuentes`, la carpeta `fonts` *esta en el directorio raiz* al par de la carpeta `css`;

```
../css/..
../fonts/..
```

Asi que tienes que indicarle que navegue hacia el directorio anterior y luego acceda a la carpeta `fonts` de esta manera:

```
src:url('../fonts/HurmeGeometricSans3Bold.otf');
```